# Supervisor process is not working on server(celery python)

Tags: python, django, celery, supervisord

I am trying to create the demon process for worker using supervisor.
On local machine it worked properly. 
When i created on server, one task from celery is getting executed but another task is not working.
Getting an error.

```
[2015-08-19 14:09:30,609: ERROR/MainProcess] Task vissa.tasks.__package_docs__[7f70521c-7046-4420-9166-13040848c09a] raised unexpected: IOError('wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code 1. error:\nxvfb-run: error: Xvfb failed to start\n',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/ezvsa_final/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/ezvsa_final/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/ezvsa_final/project/vissa/tasks.py", line 54, in __package_docs__
    package_docs_method(case)
  File "/var/www/ezvsa_final/project/vissa/utils.py", line 608, in package_docs_method
    pdfkit.from_file('template.html', "tmpl.pdf")
  File "/var/www/ezvsa_final/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pdfkit/api.py", line 46, in from_file
    return r.to_pdf(output_path)
  File "/var/www/ezvsa_final/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pdfkit/pdfkit.py", line 119, in to_pdf
    raise IOError("wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code {0}. error:\n{1}".format(exit_code, stderr.decode("utf-8")))
IOError: wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code 1. error:
xvfb-run: error: Xvfb failed to start
```

My celery.conf file is

```
[program:celery]
command = /var/www/ezvsa_final/bin/python /var/www/ezvsa_final/project/manage.py celery worker -l info
directory = /var/www/ezvsa_final/project

user=consultadd
numprocs=1
environment=C_FORCE_ROOT="yes"
stdout_logfile = /var/log/celeryd.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/celeryd.err
autostart = true
redirect_stderr=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
```

If run the worker without using supervisor(Demon) using command.

```
python manage.py celery worker -l info
```

its working properly.
I don't know why this is happening.
I think there is a issue in command i am using above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an issue in the command - this has nothing to do with supervisor - it is quite clear in the logs:

> IOError: wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code 1. error:
>
> xvfb-run: error: Xvfb failed to start

google that error message and you should find a solution